# Generate sound with pich and duration

Tags: php, audio, csound

Is possible to generate a sound in PHP with a defined note pitch and duration?

I know exists [CSOUND](http://www.csounds.com/) but I don't know how to call it from PHP and if exists a CSOUND API for PHP, as I found one in language C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a standard api or package for it. You could try using the [unix command](http://aam.mathematik.uni-freiburg.de/IAM/Info/locdocu/Csound/6/a.html) for csound (provided you have it installed).

Comment: I was thinking about to create a score and partiture file and then execute it launching csound from unix command.